# Simple HTML Dom: anomaly on iteration

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have to parse the following html code:

```
<ul>
<li><span><input id="testing_5" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="5"></span><label for="testing_5"><div>Label 1</div><span>579<span></label></li>
<li><span><input id="testing_4" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="4"></span><label for="testing_4"><div>Label 2</div><span>356<span></label></li>
<li><span><input id="testing_3" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="3"></span><label for="testing_3"><div>Label 3</div><span>109<span></label></li>
<li><span><input id="testing_2" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="2"></span><label for="testing_2"><div>Label 4</div><span>32<span></label></li>
<li><span><input id="testing_1" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="1"></span><label for="testing_1"><div>Label 5</div><span>13<span></label></li>
</ul>
```

I want to print the code inside any lable, so I wrote a simple PHP script like the follows:

```
$scrape_obj = str_get_html('<ul><li><span><input id="testing_5" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="5"></span><label for="testing_5"><div>Label 1</div><span>579<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_4" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="4"></span><label for="testing_4"><div>Label 2</div><span>356<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_3" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="3"></span><label for="testing_3"><div>Label 3</div><span>109<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_2" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="2"></span><label for="testing_2"><div>Label 4</div><span>32<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_1" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="1"></span><label for="testing_1"><div>Label 5</div><span>13<span></label></li></ul>');

$obj = $scrape_obj->find("label[for^='testing_']");
for($i=0; $i<count($obj); $i++) {

  echo "\n Number $i\n $obj[$i]\n\n";

}
```

This is the output:

```
 Number 0
 <label for="testing_5"><div>Label 1</div><span>579<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_4" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="4"></span><label for="testing_4"><div>Label 2</div><span>356<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_3" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="3"></span><label for="testing_3"><div>Label 3</div><span>109<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_2" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="2"></span><label for="testing_2"><div>Label 4</div><span>32<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_1" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="1"></span><label for="testing_1"><div>Label 5</div><span>13<span></label></li></ul>


 Number 1
 <label for="testing_4"><div>Label 2</div><span>356<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_3" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="3"></span><label for="testing_3"><div>Label 3</div><span>109<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_2" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="2"></span><label for="testing_2"><div>Label 4</div><span>32<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_1" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="1"></span><label for="testing_1"><div>Label 5</div><span>13<span></label></li></ul>


 Number 2
 <label for="testing_3"><div>Label 3</div><span>109<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_2" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="2"></span><label for="testing_2"><div>Label 4</div><span>32<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_1" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="1"></span><label for="testing_1"><div>Label 5</div><span>13<span></label></li></ul>


 Number 3
 <label for="testing_2"><div>Label 4</div><span>32<span></label></li><li><span><input id="testing_1" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="1"></span><label for="testing_1"><div>Label 5</div><span>13<span></label></li></ul>


 Number 4
 <label for="testing_1"><div>Label 5</div><span>13<span></label></li></ul>
```

The correct output must be:

```
 Number 0
 <label for="testing_5"><div>Label 1</div><span>579<span></label>

 Number 1
 <label for="testing_4"><div>Label 2</div><span>356<span></label>

 Number 2
 <label for="testing_3"><div>Label 3</div><span>109<span></label>

 Number 3
 <label for="testing_2"><div>Label 4</div><span>32<span></label>

 Number 4
 <label for="testing_1"><div>Label 5</div><span>13<span></label>
```

How can I fix it?

**SOLUTION**

The problem is the unclosed span tags. You can solve it with a simple regex:

```
$pattern = "/<span>([0-9]+)<span>/";
$replacement = "<span>$1</span>";
$html_code = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $html_code);
```

Where $html_code contains the code to parse.

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with the second _span_, it's not closed correctly  `<span>579<span></label></li>`

Comment: @Marcelo Thank you! This is the problem. I will post a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `substr()` and `strpos()` to find where the first label block ends.

Put this in your loop just before your echo:

```
$obj[$i] = substr($obj[$i],0,strpos($obj[$i],'</label>')+8);
```